# Highlight text winthin an LaTeX environment

Tags: latex, tex, texstudio

I'm currently writing a big report. In order to classify what tasks remain to do, I would like to highlight not reviewed parts of the report (like green for "Grammar check", red for "Need reformulation"...)

To do so, I need like to highlight large paragraphs, containing enumerates and figures.
I tried the "soul" package with the \hl command, but I have to apply it on each line of text, which is quickly annoying.

I would like to have an enviroment for it, something like

```
\begin{highlight}
# My text
\end{highlight}
```

I already tried to create an environment with mdframed

```
\newenvironment{grammarcheck}%
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green]}{\end{mdframed}}
```

But the result is just a big colored block with my text in it. That's not the result I want.  I would like something more similar to the highlight function of Adobe Acrobat.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the result you have in mind?

Comment: Please also add a test document including the tricky parts for which soul did not work.

Comment: There are many packages like [pdfreview](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfreview) or others that may help :)